# Series overlap in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

On bar and column charts, how do you control the series overlap in highcharts? What is the properties name?

In powerpoint this is how I would control the gap between the inside of the bars:

[image]

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=41546 - if I understand correctly the code sample shown in the linked source, you can use `groupPadding` and `pointPadding`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `pointPadding` property. Also `groupPadding` can also be useful for you.

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointPadding: 0.2
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/782qwgnr/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.pointPadding

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.groupPadding